# Cast to Active Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to cast to an active window on a wpf application, but it says I am missing a cast.  Can anyone show me the error of my ways?

```
      error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<Callisto.CallistoWindow> to Callisto.CallistoWindow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

     //Code
     CallistoWindow callistoWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CallistoWindow>();
```

Thanks for your help as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CallistoWindow>()` returns a collection of windows. Since you want only one window, you have multiple options:

- get the first window in the collection using the [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) method
- get the window that you want by some predicate using the [Single()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Examples:

```
CallistoWindow window1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CallistoWindow>().First();
CallistoWindow window2 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CallistoWindow>().Single(w => w.Name == "MainWindow");
```

You can also use `Application.Current.MainWindow` to get the main window.

Comment: Thanks GregaMohorko I should have thought of that.